# 'Press and hold' animation without NSTimer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, caanimation

**Update:** The NSTimer approach works now, but comes with a huge performance hit. The question is now narrowed down to an approach **without** NSTimers.

I'm trying to animate a 'Press and hold' interactive animation. After following a load of SO answers, I've mostly followed the approach in Controlling Animation Timing by @david-rönnqvist. And it works, if I use a Slider to pass the `layer.timeOffset`.

However, I can't seem to find a good way to continuously update the same animation on a press and hold gesture. The animation either doesn't start, only shows the beginning frame or at some points finishes and refuses to start again.

Can anyone help with achieving the following effect, **without** the horrible NSTimer approach I'm currently experimenting with?

1. On user press, animation starts, circle fills up.
2. While user holds (not necessarily moving the finger), the animation should continue until the end and stay on that frame.
3. When user lifts finger, the animation should reverse, so the circle is empties again.
4. If the user lifts his finger during the animation or presses down again during the reverse, the animation should respond accordingly and either fill or empty from the current frame.

[image: The animation I want to achieve, but by pressing and holding]

Here's a [Github repo](https://github.com/SpacyRicochet/FillingCircleTestProject) with my current efforts.

As mentioned, the following code works well. It's triggered by a slider and does its job great.

```
func animationTimeOffsetToPercentage(percentage: Double) {
    if fillShapeLayer == nil {
        fillShapeLayer = constructFillShapeLayer()
    }

    guard let fillAnimationLayer = fillShapeLayer, let _ = fillAnimationLayer.animationForKey("animation") else {
        print("Animation not found")
        return
    }

    let timeOffset = maximumDuration * percentage
    print("Set animation to percentage \(percentage) with timeOffset: \(timeOffset)")

    fillAnimationLayer.timeOffset = timeOffset
}
```

However, the following approach with NSTimers works, but has an incredible performance hit. I'm looking for an approach which doesn't use the NSTimer.

```
func beginAnimation() {
    if fillShapeLayer == nil {
        fillShapeLayer = constructFillShapeLayer()
    }

    animationTimer?.invalidate()
    animationTimer = NSTimer.schedule(interval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [unowned self] () -> Void in
        if self.layer.timeOffset >= 1.0 {
            self.layer.timeOffset = self.maximumDuration
        }
        else {
            self.layer.timeOffset += 0.1
        }
    })
}

func reverseAnimation() {
    guard let fillAnimationLayer = fillShapeLayer, let _ = fillAnimationLayer.animationForKey("animation") else {
        print("Animation not found")
        return
    }

    animationTimer?.invalidate()
    animationTimer = NSTimer.schedule(interval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [unowned self] () -> Void in
        if self.layer.timeOffset <= 0.0 {
            self.layer.timeOffset = 0.0
        }
        else {
            self.layer.timeOffset -= 0.1
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: why don't you use caanimations? Start the a growing scale animation on touch and then when released start another shrinking scale animation. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @ErikJohansson That might work. That would end up with 'add grow animation', '* stop and remove grow animation, * calculate new shrink animation based on time, * add shrink animation', wouldn't it? Lots of state to maintain, so it doesn't have my preference. :/

Comment: I think you can simplify this a fair amount if it's acceptable that the duration of growing and shrinking animation could be independent of the distance it needs to travel. In that case these could just be two different animations that are triggered when the touch/tap gesture begins and ends.

Comment: @SpacyRobot Possibly. but there would only ever need to be one animation active at any one time (or no animation).

Comment: Is the slider meant to control the animation or is that just used for debugging?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist That's indeed for debugging and to check whether my animation was sound. Starting and stopping the animation arbitrarily is what I'm currently after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is two-fold;

1. Make sure the animation doesn't remove itself on completion and keeps its final frame. Easily accomplished with the following lines of code;

   ```
   animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
   animation.removedOnCompletion = false
   ```
2. The hard part; you have to remove the original animation and start a new, fresh reverse animation that begins at the correct point. Doing this, gives me the following code;

   ```
   func setAnimation(layer: CAShapeLayer, startPath: AnyObject, endPath: AnyObject, duration: Double)
   {
       // Always create a new animation.
       let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")

       if let currentAnimation = layer.animationForKey("animation") as? CABasicAnimation {
           // If an animation exists, reverse it.
           animation.fromValue = currentAnimation.toValue
           animation.toValue = currentAnimation.fromValue

           let pauseTime = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
           // For the timeSinceStart, we take the minimum from the duration or the time passed. 
           // If not, holding the animation longer than its duration would cause a delay in the reverse animation.
           let timeSinceStart = min(pauseTime - startTime, currentAnimation.duration)

           // Now convert for the reverse animation.
           let reversePauseTime = currentAnimation.duration - timeSinceStart
           animation.beginTime = pauseTime - reversePauseTime

           // Remove the old animation
           layer.removeAnimationForKey("animation")
           // Reset startTime, to be when the reverse WOULD HAVE started.
           startTime = animation.beginTime
       }
       else {
           // This happens when there is no current animation happening.
           startTime = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)

           animation.fromValue = startPath
           animation.toValue = endPath
       }

       animation.duration = duration
       animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
       animation.removedOnCompletion = false

       layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animation")
   }
   ```

This [Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html) explains how to do a proper pause and resume animation, which is converted to use with the reverse animation.

Comment: Anyone that knows why the last code block doesn't format properly, is welcome to edit the question :)

Comment: It appears that the second code block didn't format properly because of the numbered list.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use slider you use `fillAnimationLayer` layer for animation

```
fillAnimationLayer.timeOffset = timeOffset
```

However, in `beginAnimation` and `reverseAnimation` functions you are using `self.layer`.

Try to replace `self.layer.timeOffset` with `self.fillShapeLayer!.timeOffset` in your timer blocks.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed an issue. Not the main issue, because fixing that immediately gave the me the performance penalties that are inherent in using NSTimers for this type of stuff. I'll update my answer to fix that at least, but sadly won't be accepting this answer yet.